# React.JS - Calling a function on `onClick` event causes `this` to be undefined in function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, this

I have the following React.JS (Next.JS) code:

```
export default class NavBar extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            menuOpen: false
        };
    }

    render() {
        return <img id="menu-button" src="/static/menu.svg" onClick={this.toggleMenu}></img>;
    }

    toggleMenu() {
        this.setState({ menuOpen: this.state.menuOpen ? false : true });
    }

};
```

However, when the image is clicked, and `toggleMenu` is called, I get an error saying that `this` is undefined. This makes sense, since the function is being put into the `onClick` event, but how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to either explicitly bind `this` context to your function like:

`this.toggleMenu.bind(this)`

or re-define your `toggleMenu` function using arrow notation which does this implicitly:

```
toggleMenu = () => {
  // method body here...
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Didn't know arrow functions did this. Good to know. I'll accept the answer once the 12 minutes are up.